# How can I convert pointer type in golang

Tags: go

I want convert something like (*float32) to (*int32)

I do this

```
var f float32 = 0.0
var p *int32 = (*int32)(&f) // error!
// cannot convert &f (type *float32) to type *int32
```

How can I do this like what I'm done in C

```
float f = 0.0;
int *ip = (*int) &fp;
```

Comment: You cannot do this in Go as Go is not C.

Comment: I don't think your C code works. It simply cast a pointer to a float into a pointer to an int which means you are misleading the runtime into thinking than an int is stored at that address (ints and floats have very different binary formats).
Go prevent you from making that sort of mistake (despite supporting the concept of pointer).

Comment: Do you _really_ want the float value read directly as an int, or are you trying to convert the float32 value to an int32 value?

Comment: I don't want convert something like "3.0" to "3". I want get the data on bit-level.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You absolutely can do this in Go. There are two ways. One safe and one unsafe:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    var f float32
    var i int32

    // unsafe
    f = 1.234
    i = *((*int32)(unsafe.Pointer(&f)))
    fmt.Println(f, i)

    // safe
    var tmp [4]byte
    f = 1.234
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(tmp[:], math.Float32bits(f))
    i = int32(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(tmp[:]))
    fmt.Println(f, i)
}
```